# Ionic: How do I hide an element on load

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

app.component.ts

```
platformReady() {
    // Call any initial plugins when ready
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        if(this.platform.is('core')){

            // this.menu.enable(false, 'mobileOnlyPages');
        }else{
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

app.templates.html

```
<button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of mobileOnlyPages" (click)="openPage(p)" ngHide="mobile_only">
          <ion-icon item-start [name]="p.icon" [color]="isActive(p)"></ion-icon>
          {{p.title}}
</button>
```

How would I hide this button onload?

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using?  Angular 2 does not have ng-show, ng-hide, use *ngIf instead.  Something like <button ion-item menuClose *ngFor="let p of mobileOnlyPages" (click)="openPage(p)" *ngIf="condition">.

Comment: Ionic 3 Angular 4

Comment: What do you mean by _on load_? What is the desired result?

Comment: on this platform ready (platform loaded): if(this.platform.is('core')){  then hide the button mobile_only }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use:

```
*ngIf="mobile_only"
```

or:

```
[class.hidden]="mobile_only"
```

on your stylesheet:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

**EDIT:**

`*ngIf` is kind of : *"Render this html tag if ____"*

while

the `[class.myClassName]` will be : *"Apply class, **myClassName**, on this html tag if ____"*

So basically there might be a situation where you actually need the tag rendered for some reason but just hidden from the user. In that situation, use the "conditional class". This is not the best explanation but I hope this makes enough sense.

This is one example of a possible situation i was talking about:
[Ionic2 button click text box toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149701/ionic2-button-click-text-box-toggle/46154010#46154010)

Comment: You're right but it could use a more detailed explanation. I had to work around with some other scripts to realize how to use *ngif