# Ionic 2 button click text box toggle

Tags: ionic3

I am a beginner in Ionic. I want to toggle `textbox(ion-input)` on button click. I am sending the following code it is not working. Please suggest some suggestions to solve them. The `openTheTextBox` function change the hide boolean variable into its opposite. But every time the `ion-input` is invisible state.

**HTML file**

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar>
 <button ion-button menuToggle>
 <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
 </button>
 <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
 <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>
 <p>
    If you get lost, the <a 
    href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will show you the way.
 </p>

 <button ion-button secondary menuToggle round>Toggle Menu</button>

 <button ion-button color="secondary" round full  (click)="openTheTextBox()" >Add </button>

 <ion-input type="text" value="asdasdasd" *ngIf="hide"></ion-input>

 <ion-list>
   <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of DataArray" >
   {{ item.user_name }}
  </button>  
 </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

**TS File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyDataProvider } from '../../providers/my-data/my-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public DataArray: Array<Object>;
public hide: boolean = true;
constructor(public navCtrl: 
NavController,myDataProvider:MyDataProvider) {
alert("Home Page");
type Product = { name: string; user_name: string; location: string };
let passDataObject =  { name: "jit", user_name: "j.comp", location: 
"kolkata" };
// myDataProvider.saveTablicaToSqlite(passDataObject);
let jitSaveData = myDataProvider.getTablicaMyOfflineData().then(
(result)=>{
this.DataArray = <Array<Object>> result;
alert("Length of the Array is "+this.DataArray.length)
}, (error) => {
console.log("ERROR: ", error);
});

}

openTheTextBox()
{
 alert("openTheTextBox");
 this.hide = !this.hide;
}

}
```

Comment: Is it `text box` toggle or `side navigation` toggle ?

Comment: The text box toggle on Add button click

Comment: Is there any thing wrong in the code Or I have to write some more additional  information.

Comment: Show you want to `show` and `hide` `ion-input` on button click?

Comment: Check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/geniuscarrier/tKZjZ/

Comment: Thank you guys I got my answer. Now its working. Its is a saving Issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ion-input to this:

```
<ion-input type="text" value="asdasdasd"  [class.hidden]="hide"></ion-input>
```

or `hide== true`. Which ever works for you.

then to your `.scss`, add:

```
page-home {
    ion-input.hidden {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The point is you have a conditional class for when to apply the class named "hidden". The *ngIf* is a condition for "if the html shoud be rendered", so if it happens that the tag was not rendered initially because of the condition, then you won't have it rendered anymore. So basically, have it rendered at the first place and just hide it with your boolean property that can be toggled.